# Kibana 6.5.4 does not import all exported saved objects and no reason is provided

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

Here is what happens

1. I export all the saved objects from one kibana instance with the function: `Management/Saved Objects/Export X objects`
2. I try to import the exported objects with `Management/Saved Objects/Import
3. When selecting the right file, and clicking on `Import`, I get a similar message to

```
Import successful
Successfully imported Y objects.
```

X is a lot more than Y.

I have no logs in browser console, and also no logs that can give any clue in kibana's server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have run into this problem. Form me it happened because in the Kibana that I exported the object from, there was a plugin installed (enhanced-data-table), and in the Kibana where I tired to import, the plugin was not yet installed.

After installing enhanced-data-table on the new Kibana, it imported all visualisations.

At least a warning message would be nice while importing with missing plugin.